# Shifted exponentials functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Define the set of functions $(f_m)$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\to(0,\infty)$ is given by $$f_m(x)=\exp(x+m)$$
How is it possible to prove that the functions $f_m$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Linearly independent over what? Certainly not over the reals.  They **are**  linearly independent over the rationals. Maybe it's a typo for $e^{mx}$, which are linearly independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If we had a non-trivial linear relation with rational coefficients, then $e$ would be an *algebraic number*. But $e$ is known to be *transcendental* (first proved by Hermite).

**Added:** For simplicity of notation suppose that $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k e^{k}e^x=0$, where the $a_k$ are rational. Then $e$ would be a root of the polynomial equation
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k t^k=0.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$f_m(x)=e^mf_0(x)$$

Hence these are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$.  To prove they are independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ you need to consider the set $\{e^k:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$
$~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: How do you prove that $\{e^k:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ are linearly independent?

Comment: Take a nontrivial linear combination of at least one of them, set it equal to zero, derive a contradiction.

Comment: @vadim123 One would need to resort to the fact $e$ is transcendental. Maybe the OP is unaware of this?