# Power of exponentials functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

A follow-up question to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/470855/90908) and this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470855/shifted-exponential-functions#comment1013536_470855).

Define the set of functions $(f_m)$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\to(0,\infty)$ is given by $$f_m(x)=\exp(m x)$$
How is it possible to prove that the functions $f_m$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Alternate hint: Consider the limit, as x goes to infinity, of a finite linear combination of these functions.

Comment: @SteveKass Could you elaborate on the hint?

Comment: For large $x$, $f(x)=\sum_{i=-n}^n c_i e^{ix} \approx c_n e^{nx}$ (if $c_n\neq 0$). Can $f(x)=0$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the Hessian evaluated at $0$ and look up [Vandermonde matrix.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

Comment: This is an amazing proof! Is this kind of approach common?

Comment: The Vandermonde determinant shows up "naturally" pretty often. Hessian is as you probably know an absolutely standard technique.